# React hook form, edit a form with multiple images - React JS

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, react-hook-form

I'm coding the editing part of a form, I'm using the react hook form to manipulate the data. However, when I go to edit a pet (my system is about pet adoption), I want to edit just one piece of pet data (the name, for example) and the pet's image is edited together, leaving the image empty

I tried several methods to join the data I got from the api, with the data I received from the form. But nothing worked, so I left it this way to update the images

```
const [pet, setPet] = useState({});  // recive the data that complet the form with default values
 useEffect(() => {
    api
      .get(`/pets/${id}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${JSON.parse(token)}`,
        },
      })
      .then((resp) => {
        setPet(resp.data.pet);
      });
  }, [token, id]);


  const updatePet = async (petData) => { // function to update tha data
    let msgType = "success";
    const formData = new FormData();

    const petFormData = Object.keys(petData).forEach((key) => { // i guess here is the problem
      if (key === "images") {
        for (let i = 0; i < petData[key].length; i++) {
          formData.append(`images`, petData[key][i]);
        } 
      } else {
        formData.append(key, petData[key]);
      }
    });

    formData.append("pet", petFormData);

    const data = await api
      .patch(`pets/${id}`, formData, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${JSON.parse(token)}`,
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        window.location.reload()
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        msgType = "error";
        return err.response.data;
      });


    setFlashMessage(data.message, msgType);
  };
```